# Voxel layer ArcGIS

Tags: python, arcgis-pro, netcdf, xarray, voxel

This is the Python code to create a NC file using xarray library and NetCDF4. However, when it was loaded as a voxel layer in ArcGIS Pro, it wasn't able to display all the data. Only 4 data points have geometry.

```
Save New Duplicate & Edit Just Text Twitter
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr
import netCDF4 as nc

nx = 3
ny = 3
nz = 2
delta = 500
# 3,520,176 data points

# vary x, then y and finally z
results = []

for nz_sample in range(nz):
    z_start = -68.98999786376953
    z_start += nz_sample * delta

    for ny_sample in range(ny):
        y_start = 31876.69921875
        y_start += ny_sample * delta

        for nx_sample in range(nx):
            x_start = 28535.189453125
            x_start += (nx_sample) * delta

            result = [x_start, y_start, z_start]

            results.append(result)

# print(len(results))
# results
df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['x', 'y', 'z']).set_index(['x', 'y', 'z'])

# print(df.shape)
# df.head()
test_df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\hzhang\Desktop\test2.csv')
# skiprows=13
# test_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print(test_df.head())
# test_df.fillna(9999.9)
# print(test_df.head())
print(test_df.shape)
df['value'] = test_df.loc[:].values
print(df.head())
print(df.tail())
print(len(df))
# df.to_csv('testfile.csv')
df.to_csv('testfile3.csv')
xr = df.to_xarray()
xr.x.attrs['units'] = 'm'
xr.y.attrs['units'] = 'm'
xr.x.attrs['standard_name'] = 'projection_x_coordinate'
xr.x.attrs['long_name'] = 'x-coordinate in projected coordinate system'
xr.y.attrs['standard_name'] = 'projection_y_coordinate'
xr.y.attrs['long_name'] = 'y-coordinate in projected coordinate system'

xr.z.attrs['units'] = 'm'
xr.z.attrs['standard_name'] = 'projection_z_coordinate'
xr.z.attrs['long_name'] = 'z-coordinate in projected coordinate system'

xr['transverse_mercator'] = float()
xr.transverse_mercator.attrs['grid_mapping_name'] = 'transverse_mercator'
# xr.transverse_mercator.attrs['standard_parallel'] = 'transverse_mercator'
xr.transverse_mercator.attrs['scale_factor_at_central_meridian'] = 1.
xr.transverse_mercator.attrs['latitude_of_projection_origin'] = 1.366666666666667
xr.transverse_mercator.attrs['longitude_of_central_meridian'] = 103.8333333333333
xr.transverse_mercator.attrs['false_easting'] = 28001.642
xr.transverse_mercator.attrs['false_northing'] = 38744.572
# xr.transverse_mercator.attrs['semi_major_axis'] = 6378137.0
print(xr.transverse_mercator)
xr.value.attrs['grid_mapping'] = 'transverse_mercator'


print(xr["x"].encoding)
print(xr.info())
xr.to_netcdf('test.nc', encoding={'x': {'dtype': 'double','_FillValue': 9999.9}, 'y': {'dtype': 'double', '_FillValue': 9999.9}, 'z': {'dtype': 'double','_FillValue': 9999.9}, 'value': {'dtype': 'double','_FillValue': 9999.9}})
# fn = r'C:\Users\hzhang\Desktop\test.nc'
# ds = nc.Dataset(fn)
# print(ds.dimensions)
# print(ds.variables)
#
# lat = ds.createVariable('latitude', 'f8', ('x'),)
# lon = ds.createVariable('longitude', 'f8', ('y'),)
```

(code also available at: https://paste.pythondiscord.com/izajanuquv.py)

Comment: Please include the code in the body of text rather than a link.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please remember to always include a minimal code sample that reproduces your issue in your coding questions. Links break over time, and it's bad security practice to follow them anyway, so you're effectively limiting the number of folks available to help you.

Comment: unfortunately i cant seem to find the issue, I tried putting the whole code but it was too long

Comment: thank you @RafDouglas